# How to use Twitter Insights and retrieve data out there?

Tags: api, twitter, analytics

In Twitter Analytics Under Audience Insights I can see my followers Interests,Gender and etc. See the attached image

I have skimmed through some APIs of Twitter but I am still unsure about how to retrieve those data programmatically..

Which API documentation should I take into account as a reference? Also is it a necessity to be an official partner to reach those data or not?

[image: analytics dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

Not all of this data is available via API today, but some of it is. There are two possible sources of this data via API:

1. The Ads API has [Audience Insights](https://dev.twitter.com/ads/campaigns/audience-insights) endpoints for whitelisted partners that provide insights into the audiences of advertisers. These include two endpoints: [GET insights/accounts/:account_id](https://dev.twitter.com/ads/reference/get/insights/accounts/%3Aaccount_id) and [GET insights/accounts/:account_id/available_audiences](https://dev.twitter.com/ads/reference/get/insights/accounts/:account_id/available_audiences)
2. The GNIP APIs also have an [Audience Insights](https://gnip.com/insights/audience/) API in beta that exposes more data that the Ads API. The [reference for this API](http://support.gnip.com/apis/audience_api/) is available now.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But still couldnt catch the point, To use ads api is it a necessity to be a partner ? or any company can use it for the benefit of themselves or not ?

Comment: To use the Ads API, you must apply to be a partner. The program began to open up in Spring 2015. You can apply for access at https://dev.twitter.com/ads. For GNIP access, those endpoints require paid access.